# How to connect to Postgres database through Ruby's pg gem (outside of Rails)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I've been using Postgres without issue within Rails and have also been running `psql` without issue. However, I'm running into a problem trying to connect to the database with the `pg` gem.

The following code:

```
PG.connect
```

generates the error/output:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The result is the same whether I specify various `dbname:` values or not or just let this default.

When I click on the little elephant icon at the top of my screen, it says "Running on port 5432" and, as I said, I can connect with `psql` without a problem.

I found the very similar [cannot connect to Postgres (pg) database from my Ruby Script using gem "pg"(This is not rails, just pure ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685649/cannot-connect-to-postgres-pg-database-from-my-ruby-script-using-gem-pgthis), but the answer simply said Rails works fine.

Any guidance would be appreciated. (Note: I realize I haven't entered any name/password info, but I don't have to enter than when I run `psql` and I gather it's not getting to the point of authentication).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify a host.  It's trying to connect on a unix domain socket.  The PG app doesn't listen on a unix socket (unless you configure it to) but runs on localhost:5432.

```
 conn = PG.connect( host: 'localhost' )
```

Comment: Thanks. That took care of it. I'll accept later this evening (gotta run now).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that the actual problem is that your 'pg' gem has linked to an older version of a `libpq` dynamic library.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627465/ruby-pg-gem-linking-to-wrong-copy-of-libpq-5-dylib-on-osx) for more details and a possible solution.